# Product created on development workspace for some reason appear on master workspace (VTEX)

Tags: javascript, node.js, e-commerce, product, admin

I have a question related to Vtex platrform. When I create a product on my development workspace in the admin panel this product for some reason is also created on my master workspace. How to fix this?

Thank’s in advance for any help.

I create a product on dev workspace and this product exist only on dev workspace and not on master workspace

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the VTEX platform the creation of products is not segmented by workspace. This means that even if you create a product logged in a development workspace, this product is going to be created in all workspaces, even in the master env. If you need to test the creation of products or something related to catalog without interfering with the master workspace you have to have to a QA account.